# Фантомная ошибка по вебсокетам android

Tags: php, java, android-studio, websocket

пишу после того, как 3 дня бился с этой проблемой.
Никак не могу понять почему так происходит:

1. После того как я захожу в приложение которое пару раз перезапустил, мне прилетают уведы по вебсокетам
2. Выхожу из приложения, чищу память, захожу снова заказы не прилетают на вебсокеты, при этом в логах пишется, что я подключен к серверу и он это тоже подтверждает
3. После перезапуска приложения раза 2 проблема пропадает
4. Решил глянуть отпраляет ли месседж вебсокет и тут увидел, что он не отправляет сообщения хотя клиент в коннекте

Подскажите подалйста, что это может быть, у меня несколько вебсокет подключений, но только это морочит мозги

Хочу заметить, что этот вебсокет расположен в фрагменте. Может это будет ключем к разгадке?

```
private void connectToSocket() {
        URI uri;
        try {
            uri = new URI("ури");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            Log.d("----uri------",e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
        mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri, new Draft_17()) {
            @Override
            public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
                Log.d("Websocket", "Opened");
            }
            @Override
            public void onMessage(String s) {
                Log.d("--mes--", s);
                try {
                    socketCars(s);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b) {
                Log.d("Websocket", "Closed " + s);
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                Log.d("Websocket", "Error " + e.getMessage());
            }
        };
        mWebSocketClient.connect();
    }

private void socketCars(String s) throws InterruptedException {
        DBClass = new DBClass();
        String hash = DBClass.getHash(binding.getRoot().getContext());
        String url = URL_API + "/";
        countOrders = binding.getRoot().findViewById(R.id.count);


        Runnable ord = () -> {
            countOrders = binding.getRoot().findViewById(R.id.count);
            list = binding.getRoot().findViewById(R.id.listView);
            try {
                if(!HttpApi.getId(url).equals("0")) {
                    if (!HttpApi.getId(URL_API_CAR + hash).equals("0")) {
                        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<RootAllOrders>>() {
                        }.getType();
                        List<RootAllOrders> orders = new Gson().fromJson(HttpApi.getId(url), listType);
                        RootCars rootCars = new Gson().fromJson(HttpApi.getId(URL_API_CAR + hash), RootCars.class);
                        int count = 0;
                        for (int j = 0; j < orders.size(); j++) {
                            if (orders.get(j).getClassOrder().equals(rootCars.getClassCar()))
                                count++;
                        }
                        String orC = "У вас " + count + " новых запросов";
                        requireActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> countOrders.setText(orC));
                        data = new String[count][6];
                        dataImg = new int[count];
                        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                            if (orders.get(i).getClassOrder().equals(rootCars.getClassCar())) {
                                arrayInp(i, orders);
                            }
                        }
                        newData = cityOrders(data, orders);
                        newImg = dataImgOrders(data, orders);
                        if(ordersIsCity(data)) {
                            String orCN = "У вас " + newImg.length + " новых запросов";
                            requireActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> countOrders.setText(orCN));
                        }
                    }
                    if(ordersIsCity(data)) {
                        requireActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> list.setAdapter(new AdaptorOrders(binding.getRoot().getContext(), newData, newImg)));
                    } else {
                        requireActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> list.setAdapter(new AdaptorOrders(binding.getRoot().getContext(), data, dataImg)));
                    }
                } else {
                    String [][] d = new String[0][6];
                    int [] dImg = new int[0];
                    requireActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> list.setAdapter(new AdaptorOrders(binding.getRoot().getContext(), d, dImg)));
                    requireActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> countOrders.setText("У вас 0 новых запросов"));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("лог", e.getMessage());
            }
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(ord);
        thread.start();
        thread.join();

        try {
            Uri notify = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(binding.getRoot().getContext(), notify);
            r.play();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Данные с сервака, при каждом отправлении он должен писать тру

```
New connection 
New connection 
true
```

И наконец сам вебсокет сервер

```
use Workerman\Worker;

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once "/var/www/html/DB/DB_connect.php";
require '/var/www/html/API/orders/orders.php';

$wsWorker = new Worker('websocket://0.0.0.0:27810');
$wsWorker->count = 4;

$wsWorker->onConnect = function ($connection) {
    echo "New connection \n";
};

$wsWorker->onMessage = function ($connection, $data) use ($wsWorker, &$conn){

    foreach ($wsWorker->connections as $clientConnections){
        $clientConnections->send(json_encode("true"));
        echo "true"."      ";
    }

   
};

$wsWorker->onClose = function ($connection){
    echo "Closed \n";
};

Worker::runAll();
```

Заранее благодарен за ответы

Comment: скорее всего это mailware блочит на уровне клиента или выше. Пробуй отдельно передавать